# Cloud Custodian offhour policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, cloudcustodian

Goal: Using [Cloud Custodian](https://cloudcustodian.io/docs/quickstart/offhours.html), I want EC2 instance to stop on every Monday morning at 7AM CST and start every Sunday night at 11PM CST. (This EC2 instance will run for 8 hrs every Monday to do specific task and remaining time it should remain shutdown). This is going to be opt-in policy

Can someone please check my written policy below. I am trying to use tag based configuration to make this happen. Don't know how?

```
- name: ec2-off-hours-stop
  resource: ec2
  comments: |
    Stop EC2 instances, every monday morning at 7:00 AM (CST)
  filters:
    - type: offhour
      default_tz: ct
      tag: c7n_maid_offhours
      opt-out: false
      offhour: 7    (How do I mention Monday? off=M,7)
  mode:
      schedule: "rate(60 minutes)"
      type: periodic
      execution-options:
        output_dir: s3://abcdreports/abcdLogs/{account_id}/
  actions:
    - stop

- name: ec2-off-hours-start
  resource: ec2
  comments: |
    Start EC2 instances, every sunday night at 11:00 PM (CST)
  filters:
    - type: onhour
      default_tz: ct
      tag: c7n_maid_offhours
      opt-out: false
      onhour: 23 (How do I mention Sunday? on=U,23)
  mode:
      schedule: "rate(60 minutes)"
      type: periodic
      execution-options:
        output_dir: s3://abcdreports/abcdLogs/{account_id}/
  actions:
    - start
```

Answer (score 0):

a tag value with "off=(M,7);on=(S,18)" would do that, we don't support day configuration within the action outside of weekend only specification. you could perhaps use a value filter though to compare the current date. file an issue if its something of interest.